# Impossible to add a new language

Tags: wordpress, polylang

After a clean install of Polylang (v 3.3.1) on Wordpress (6.1.1 up to date), I can add any language via the 'Add a new language' button.

The error message is : **impossible to add an new language**.

It is impossible for me also to add a new language via polylang config panel.

How did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find why : the database contained old data.

I de-install polylang
I backup my site
I install WP-Optimize and clean the database completely
I install polylang

No more error when adding a new language.